# Where can I see all the comments I have posted?

Tags: discussion, comments

Under the responses tab. `?tab=responses`, it shows me *some* of the comments I have posted. More specifically, it shows me incoming messages that have been exclusively to me. Can I see *all* the comments I have posted, regardless if they were up-voted, or any other context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to go to activity tab, and then the comments subtab.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/654953/rpm?tab=activity&sort=comments

[image]